# How to create a simple C library using a header file

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, header-files

I have looked online and cannot get the syntax exactly right. I am trying to create a header file so I can use a function in another C source file. The function is called `readLine()` and it resides in `myown.c`. I want to use it in `myown3.c`.

Here is the header file `myown.h`:

```
#define LINECAP 81
#ifndef MYOWN_H
#define MYOWN_H
void readLine ( char buffer [], LINECAP);
#endif
```

Here is `myown.c`

```
#include "myown.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void readLine ( char buffer [], int lineCapacity)   {
char  myCharacter;
  int i = 0 ;
  do {
    myCharacter = getchar();
    buffer[i] = myCharacter;
    i++;
  } while (myCharacter != '\n'  && i < lineCapacity );
  buffer [i-1] = '\0';
}

void cleanBuffer ( char buffer [])  {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<81; i++)
    buffer[i] =0;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])   {
/* void readLine ( char buffer [], int lineCapactiy); */
void cleanBuffer(char buffer []);

  int i;
  char line[81];
  for (i=0; i<3; i++)  {
     //cleanBuffer(line);
     readLine(line,LINECAP);
     printf("%s", line);
     //cleanBuffer(line);
  }
}
```

Here is the `myown3.c`, which I want to use the function in:

```
#include "myown.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
bool alphabetic ( const char c) {
  //if ((c > 65 && c < 90)  || (c > 97 && c < 122))
  if (( c > 'a' && c < 'z') || ( c > 'A' && c < 'Z'))
     return true;
  else
     return false;
}

int countWords ( const char string[])    {
   int i, wordCount =0;
   bool lookingForWord= true, alphabetic (const char c);
   for ( i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
     if (alphabetic(string[i])) {
         wordCount++;
         lookingForWord = false;
     } else {
         lookingForWord = true;
     }
   }
  return wordCount;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])  {
  char text[81];
  int totalWords =0;
  int countWords ( const char string[]);
  /* void readLine (char buffer[], int lineCapacity); */
  bool endOfText = false;
  printf ("Type in your text.\n");
  printf ("Wehn you are done, press 'RETURN'.\n");
  while ( ! endOfText )    {
    readLine (text, 81);

    if ( text[0] == '\0')
      endOfText = true;
    else
    totalWords == countWords (text);
  }
  printf ("\nThere are %i words in the above text.\n", totalWords);
  return 0;
}
```

I get the following error when I try to compile:

```
gcc -I. myown.c -o myown
In file included from myown.c:1:0:
myown.h:1:17: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant
 #define LINECAP 81
                 ^
myown.h:4:33: note: in expansion of macro 'LINECAP'
 void readLine ( char buffer [], LINECAP);
                                 ^
make: *** [myown] Error 1
```

Everything worked. It took me some time to figure out I have to compile and link the parts separately. I got the following error when I tried to compile things all at once:

```
$ gcc -I. myown3.c -o myown3
C:\Users\sansari\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYfmI6U.o:myown3.c:(.text+0xd1): undefined reference to `readLine'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But the following commands worked....

```
gcc myown.c -c -o myown.o
gcc myown3.c -c -o myown3.o
gcc myown3.o myown.o -o myown3
```

Comment: What is the second argument to `readLine` supposed to be?

Comment: on a side note, You can use standard libraries stuff for thing like alphanum check, e.g. `isalnum(character)`. check `ctype.h` for more stuff.

Comment: 2 general comments, first off, you want that # define in your include protection in the header file. Helps avoid warnings of redeclarations.

Secondly, you are using a constant in your function prototype, which differs from your function definition. You would want to change the prototype to match (use the `int`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paulsm almost got it right:

```
#ifndef MYOWN_H
#define MYOWN_H

#define LINECAP 81

void readLine(char buffer[], int lineCapacity);

#endif
```

The *types* of the arguments must be declared in the prototype of `readLine()`, not some constant that resolves to 81. 81 is not a valid *type*, nor is `LINECAP`.

Since `myown.c` has a `main()` that conflicts with `myown3.c`'s `main()`, you should think about putting the definition of `readLine()` in a new file (say, `mylib.c`) and link that to `myown.c` for the first program and to `myown3.c` for the second. I would rename the header to `mylib.h` too.

So then you have:

mylib.h:

```
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

#define LINECAP 81

void readLine(char buffer[], int lineCapacity);

#endif
```

mylib.c:

```
#include "myown.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void readLine ( char buffer [], int lineCapacity)
{
  char myCharacter;
  int i = 0 ;
  do 
  {
    myCharacter = getchar();
    buffer[i] = myCharacter;
    i++;
  } while (myCharacter != '\n'  && i < lineCapacity );
  buffer [i-1] = '\0';
}
```

And `readLine()` is removed from `myown.c`

So now the files are:

- library `mylib.c` with `mylib.h` (and no `main()`)
- program `myown.c`, including `mylib.h` and linking to `mylib.c`
- program `myown3.c`, including `mylib.h` and linking to `mylib.c`

And in your code, you can finally use the constant:

```
readLine(text, LINECAP);
```

instead of

```
readLine(text, 81);
```

wherever you use `81` for the line capacity (e.g. in `cleanBuffer()`), you should use `LINECAP`, so if you want to change the capacity one day, you only have to change the value `81` to something else, *in only one place* (`mylib.h`).

I would advise you to put some other re-usable functions in `mylib.c` too.

Comment: And use `LINECAP` in most places where the code currently uses `81`.

Comment: Indeed. That is what such `#define`s are for, to define such value in one single place, so modifying that one single define is enough to change it everywhere. @JonathanLeffler, you know that, but obviously maverick doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

*REMOVE* your redundant prototypes for "void readLine()"; just use "myown.h" instead:

```
#ifndef MYOWN_H
#define MYOWN_H

#define LINECAP 81

void readLine ( char buffer [], int linecap);

#endif
```

MAIN PROBLEMS:

- Don't put a constant (LINECAP) inside a prototype.
- In "myown.h", put the "define* *INSIDE* of your [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard):
- You don't need the multiple prototypes at all: just define the prototype *ONCE*, inside of "myown.h".
- You must have one - and *ONLY ONE* - "main()" per executable.
- `#define LINECAP 81` only *ONCE* (in myheader.h), and use LINECAP everywhere else (instead of "81").

Comment: Did you mean to write: `void readLine(char buffer[], int lineCapacity);` in the header?

Comment: In the header it is enough to write a prototype only with data types: `void readLine (char [], int);` and put `#define LINECAP 81` inside the `#include ` guards `#ifndef MYOWN_H` ...

Comment: And two files both with `main()` aren't going to link.  It's good to have test code for the library, but it needs to be conditionally compiled.

Comment: @user3078414: Yes it is enough to write the types only, but I like it when the argument names are included as well. I hate to read headers that don't do that. It may suffice for the compiler, but not for the human that must try to understand the code.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis - I should have just copied/pasted the entire program, did my own test build, and flushed out *ALL* the errors. I updated my post- thank you for pointing out the bug in the "myheader.h" prototype!